# h:selectOneMenu,Updating the model and does not updating the view

Tags: jsf

I'm new to JSF and facing one issue with h:selectOneMenu. selectiononeMenu has  three selectionItem values(All,Checked, Unchecked).whenever I am changing the value of the dropdown, value change listener is getting triggered and view is getting updated.
I have to introduce one button that always will set the value of the dropdown to All. as part of button action, I am creating one UISelectOne and setting the value to All. Actually here model is getting updated. but dropdown selection view is not getting updated. it is still showing the old value.

Pls help me to resolve the issue

ActiveTable.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
......
</style>
    <!-- Remember to keep the script up to date whenever you change the ids or Hierarchy of components -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ....  
</script>

    <style>
.headerExtended {
    height: 70px;
}
</style>
    <f:view id="tableview"
        locale="#{sessionScope.WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE}">
        <h:panelGroup id="unsuccessfulAttemptsmsg"
            .....
        </h:panelGroup>
        <f:loadBundle basename="OMAgentResources" var="bundle" />

        <div
            style="padding: 15px 0px 25px 0px; border: none; margin-bottom: 50px;">
            <h:form id="activeForm" prependId="false">
                <a4j:region ajaxRendered="true" id="activeRegion">
                    <a4j:push id="ajaxPush" address="activeTopic" enabled="true"
                        interval="0">
                        <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" render="activeForm" />
                    </a4j:push>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="messagePanel" ajaxRendered="true">
                        <h:messages />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                    <br />
                    <h:panelGrid id="activeTablePanel" columns="1"
                        styleClass="otContentAreaAlign" width="100%">

                        <!-- EXTENDED DATA TABLE  -->
                        <rich:extendedDataTable value="#{alctiveBean.rowData}"
                            var="row" id="activeTable"
                            rows="#{preferencesBean.batchValue}" selectionMode="none"
                            style="width: 1177px;" onRowMouseOut="mouseOutRichRow(this)"
                            onRowDblClick="wuiDataTableSelectRow(this)" sortMode="single"
                            frozenColumns="2" showColumnControl="true"
                            onrowmousemove="collapseDropDown()">

                            <!-- Column for ack/clr selection -->
                            <rich:column id="ackclrColumn"
                                style="text-align:center;white-space: nowrap;"
                                headerClass="headerExtended" width="115px">
                                <f:facet name="header" id="ackclrHeader">
                                    <h:outputText id="tableformenabledcolumnheadersmall"
                                        value="#{bundle.active_page}" />
                                         <h:panelGroup id="selectionFilterPanel">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectionFilter" 
                                            valueChangeListener="#{activeBean.selectionChangeListener}"
                                            style="text-align:center;">
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{activeBean.selectionList}" />
                                            <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this"
                                                    render="activeTablePanel,activeTableButtonPanel" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                </f:facet>
                            </rich:column>
                        </rich:extendedDataTable>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </a4j:region

                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="activeTableButtonPanel"
                        style="width: 1190px; align:center">
                        <!-- Command buttons -->
                        <h:panelGroup>

                            <a4j:commandButton id="clearFiltersButtonId"
                                value="#{bundle.activebrowser_page_clr_flt}"
                                action="#{activeBean.clearFiltersAction}"
                                disabled="#{!activeBean.isFilterActive}"
                                render="activeTable,activeTableButtonPanel"
                                rendered="true"
                                style="text-align:center"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

BackEnd Bean:

selection Change listener:

```
public synchronized void selectionChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event){

        if(theSelectionFilter == null) {
            setSelectionFilter(new HtmlSelectOneMenu());
        } else {
            setSelectionFilter(theSelectionFilter);
        }


        Object oo = event.getNewValue();
        if (oo == null) {
            return;
        }
        String allEnum = ((EnumerationFilter) myFilterSelector.getFilter(
                FilterSelector.SELECTIONFILTER)).getAllEnumValue();
        String s = (String) oo;
        EnumerationFilter enumFilter =
                (EnumerationFilter)myFilterSelector.getFilter(FilterSelector.SELECTIONFILTER);

        String olds[] = enumFilter.getSelectedEnums();
        String old = allEnum;
        if (olds.length > 0) {
            old = olds[0]; //There's never more than one, this is a select-one component
        }

        enumFilter.setSelections(new String[]{s});
        if (enumFilter.allEnumSelected()){
            UISelectOne one = (UISelectOne) theSelectionFilter;
            one.setValue(allEnum);
        }
        //Refresh if selection changed
        //
        if (!old.equals(s)) {
            myRefreshRequestHolder.setRefreshRequest(true);
        }
    }
```

clearFiltersAction:

```
public synchronized String clearFiltersAction(){
        log.info("activerBean: clearFiltersAction triggered.");
        String msg = myResourceBundle.getString("general_page_doneresponse");
        myMessageContainer.setMessage(msg);
        setFacesMessage(MessageType.MESSAGE_INFO, msg);
        log.info("ActiveBean: clearFiltersAction :" + msg);
        AlarmFilter filters[] = myFilterSelector.getFilters();
        for (int i=0; i < filters.length; ++i){
            filters[i].clearFilter();
        }

        String allEnum = ((EnumerationFilter) myFilterSelector.getFilter(
                FilterSelector.SELECTIONFILTER)).getAllEnumValue();
        log.info("ActiveBean: clearFiltersAction : clearing SELECTIONFILTER");
        UISelectOne one = (UISelectOne) theSelectionFilter;
        one.isRendered();
        if (one != null) {
            one.setValue(allEnum);
            log.info("ActiveBean: clearFiltersAction : resetting SELECTIONFILTER to ALL");
        }

        EnumerationFilter enumFilter =
                (EnumerationFilter)myFilterSelector.getFilter(FilterSelector.SELECTIONFILTER);

        enumFilter.setSelections(new String[]{allEnum});

        refreshIterator(true);  
        return null;//stay in the same page
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should include your code, the HTML and the backing bean java code.

Comment: In [mcve] flavour! See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [ask] \

Comment: thanks for the response.. i have update the same with code... pls help me to resolve the issue..

Comment: thanks for the response..i have included the code now...please help me to resolve the same..